# setInterval modifying global state

Tags: javascript, redux, setinterval

I am quite new to Javascrit and Redux. I have been going over several references, and I came across this article about middleware in Redux: https://www.codementor.io/@vkarpov/beginner-s-guide-to-redux-middleware-du107uyud

The author stated that reducers should not modify global state (thus pure function), therefore reducers should not use fuctions like `setInterval`.

If I understand correctly, this means that `setInterval` does modify global state. My question would be how and which part of global state does `setInterval` modify?

Any kinds of detail would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducers should not be responsible for managing async actions. setInterval does not modify global state inherently but if it's invoked from inside a reducer it does have the potential to access and modify state through object references.

The purpose of this rule is to keep your code clean, focused, and simple. As such reducers should take a state and an action and generate a new state synchronously. No other shenanigans.

That's why Redux Thunk and Redux Sagas exist. They give us the ability to handle the many phases of async actions while keeping the logic outside the reducers.

For example, imagine the following reducer:

```js
// Simple reducer that ignores action and just adds 1 to
// state count every time
function myReducer(state, action) {
    return {
        count: state.count + 1
    };
}

// Reducer that calls setInterval
function myBadReducer(state, action) {
    // When our reducer gets called we create an interval
    // that increases count directly by 1 every 2 seconds
    // BTW This is exceptionally bad since it creates a duplicate
    // interval everytime the reducer is invoked.
    setInterval(() => {
        state.count += 1;
    }, 2000);

    return state;
}
```

The bad reducer is modifying state directly through references which breaks the flow redux has created for us. State-->Action-->Reducer-->New State. This makes it impossible for Redux to performantly notify all subscribers that the state has changed because its not monitoring every single memory address.

Instead you should setup a separate process outside the reducer (or use Redux Sagas) that calls an action as needed (on interval or however else) and let the store handle invoking the reducer and generating a new state each time.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please provide a short snippet which invokes setInterval inside reducers and accesses and modifies state through object references? Thank you again.

Comment: Thanks for your example. One follow up question is I think the reason why yourBadReducer is bad is because we are putting a code modifying state directly in setInterval and it is not setInterval's fault. We could have had the same bad thing in your good reducer by having state.count += 1 instead of returning a new staye. Am I missing something?

Comment: You are right and no you aren't missing anything. The article is a bit ambiguous in how it describes the modification of global state. You can see it attaches the interval to the action in the middleware which is ok, but doing so from the reducer would be considered not best practice. Same idea as what I have here. Keep reducers simple and straight forward.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!